# Change color in Google Map Search Box

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have search box on my site and Google Map, like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete). I need to change color of **autocomplete results**. I search everywhere, but cant find this option.

I need it, because it conflicts (may be) with jquery mobile styles, autocomplete results are transparent. How to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
.pac-container {background-color: yellow! important;}
.pac-item: hover{background-color: brown! important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the example you need to set a `background-color` for the DIV with the class `pac-container`.

The individual results are in DIVs with a class of `pac-item`

Answer (score 0):

They changed the API, this is what the structure looks like:

[image]